# Best way to implement string replace in a big file?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

This question was asked in interview. 
Given a big file, search and replace a given word. There are many ways to implement this question.
Some open ended question - how to represent the big file? Like a char array? Through stream readers ?  etc.
I was thinking on lines of GapBuffer. If the `replacement string` is longer than the `source` string, then increase the char array size, using ArrayCopy, and then do the following:

```
for (Each character going backward/reverse) {
   shift character forward by 'x' steps. 'x' is (replacement string length - source length) * (frequency of source)
   each time the match is found, then replace the string.
   reduce 'x' by (replacement string length - source length)
}
```

Any better suggestions ?

Comment: memory mapped files the best way

Comment: @Lashane: Care to elaborate on how a memory mapped file will help in this situation?

Comment: @JimMischel this will be out of the format of this site

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is one of those problems which are already solved efficiently by existing tools and shouldn't implement yourself. The interviewer probably wanted to hear about using unix tools like `sed`.

If you are asked to write code though, then the simplest way would be to use another output file and read the file part-by-part in a buffer, find/replace, write to output.